# how do I get the base_url in stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm unable to get the base_url within a stencil template. {{ settings.base_url }} always returns an empty string. https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/settings-object.

Is there another global stencil object that contains the site url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in (pencil-response.js)[https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/blob/master/server/plugins/renderer/responses/pencil-response.js#L79-L85] 
 intentionally destroys those values using a regex.

```
regex = new RegExp(internals.escapeRegex(context.settings.base_url), 'g');
content = content.replace(regex, '');
```

this commit used a value of `request.info.host`:
https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/commit/fb9611502613f00a364a8d9ea4e1d3351c834d08

I sumitted a fix in this pull request. https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/pull/396